# order by slowing down query with multiple joins and limit/offset on larger result sets

Tags: query-performance, innodb, mariadb, query

I am having trouble with the following query taking quite a long time to process when results are large.  The limit and offset can change as this is used with pagination.  The range on capture_timestamp can also change, but in this example is finding ALL results (between 0 and 9999999999 - this field is an int of utc timestamp).  The issue seems to be the ORDER BY taking up most of the processing time.  It looks like it uses `user_id` for the table join, but then never uses anything for the ordering.

On the `logs` table I have the following indexes :

```
PRIMARY : activity_id
user_id : (user_id, capture_timestamp)
capture_timestamp : capture_timestamp (added this to see if by itself would make a difference - it did not)
```

There are keys setup for all the ON joins.

This particular query for example has 2440801 results (the logs table itself is currently holding 18332067 rows), but I am only showing the first 10 sorted by capture_timestamp and it takes roughly 7 seconds to return the results.

```
SELECT
    logs.activity_id,
    users.username,
    computers.computer_name,
    computers.os,
    logs.event_title,
    logs.event_target,
    logs.capture_timestamp

FROM computers
INNER JOIN users
    ON users.computer_id = computers.computer_id
INNER JOIN logs
    ON logs.user_id = users.user_id AND logs.capture_timestamp BETWEEN :cw_date_start AND :cw_date_end
    
WHERE computers.account_id = :cw_account_id AND computers.status = 1
ORDER BY logs.capture_timestamp DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

**analyze :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ANALYZE] => {
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "r_loops": 1,
    "r_total_time_ms": 6848.2,
    "filesort": {
      "sort_key": "logs.capture_timestamp desc",
      "r_loops": 1,
      "r_total_time_ms": 431.25,
      "r_limit": 10,
      "r_used_priority_queue": true,
      "r_output_rows": 11,
      "temporary_table": {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "computers",
          "access_type": "ref",
          "possible_keys": ["PRIMARY", "account_id_2", "account_id"],
          "key": "account_id_2",
          "key_length": "4",
          "used_key_parts": ["account_id"],
          "ref": ["const"],
          "r_loops": 1,
          "rows": 294,
          "r_rows": 294,
          "r_total_time_ms": 0.4544,
          "filtered": 100,
          "r_filtered": 100,
          "attached_condition": "computers.`status` = 1"
        },
        "table": {
          "table_name": "users",
          "access_type": "ref",
          "possible_keys": ["PRIMARY", "unique_filter"],
          "key": "unique_filter",
          "key_length": "4",
          "used_key_parts": ["computer_id"],
          "ref": ["db.computers.computer_id"],
          "r_loops": 294,
          "rows": 1,
          "r_rows": 3.415,
          "r_total_time_ms": 0.7054,
          "filtered": 100,
          "r_filtered": 100,
          "using_index": true
        },
        "table": {
          "table_name": "logs",
          "access_type": "ref",
          "possible_keys": ["user_id", "capture_timestamp"],
          "key": "user_id",
          "key_length": "4",
          "used_key_parts": ["user_id"],
          "ref": ["db.users.user_id"],
          "r_loops": 1004,
          "rows": 424,
          "r_rows": 2431.1,
          "r_total_time_ms": 4745.3,
          "filtered": 100,
          "r_filtered": 100,
          "index_condition": "logs.capture_timestamp between '0' and '9999999999'"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
        )

)
```

Is there anything I can do here to speed these up?  When the result set is smaller everything is pretty much immediate although I guess that is because there isn't as much sorting to do.

**Additions :**

```
CREATE TABLE `computers` (
  `computer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `version` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `os` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `computer_uid` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `computer_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `uninstall` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `capture_timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`computer_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `account_id_2` (`account_id`,`computer_uid`),
  KEY `account_id` (`account_id`,`status`),
  CONSTRAINT `computers_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`account_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14362124 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci    

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `computer_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `changed` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ctimestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `stimestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_filter` (`computer_id`,`username`),
  CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`computer_id`) REFERENCES `computers` (`computer_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=54312 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci   

CREATE TABLE `logs` (
  `activity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `event_title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `event_target` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `capture_timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `demo` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`activity_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`,`demo`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`capture_timestamp`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `capture_timestamp` (`capture_timestamp`),
  CONSTRAINT `logs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=444156934 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: It looks like ORDER BY takes "r_total_time_ms": 431.25 while 1000 lookups to logs table  take "r_total_time_ms": 4745.3. You can improve speed of these lookups buy implementing covering indexes suggested by Rick in his answer. Better solution would be rewrite query using APPLY (like in MSSQL) or LATERAL (like in MySQL8) but unfortunately this feature is not implemented in MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

> The limit and offset can change as this is used with pagination.

> order by slowing down query with multiple joins and limit/offset on larger result sets

> WHERE computers.account_id = :cw_account_id AND computers.status = 1
> ORDER BY logs.capture_timestamp DESC

You have an unsolvable problem.

`INDEX(status, account_id)` will take care of part of the `WHERE` clause.  But the `ORDER BY` looks at a different table.  Hence, the processing will filter, write the results to a temp table, and sort that table (by `capture_timestamp`) before it can do anything with the `LIMIT`.

It is not possible (nor practical) to use indexes from two tables in a single `SELECT`.

---

Please put filtering in `WHERE` and use `ON` only for saying how the tables are related.  Now the end of the query is

```
WHERE computers.account_id = :cw_account_id
  AND computers.status = 1
  AND logs.capture_timestamp BETWEEN ... AND ...
```

---

The Optimizer will pack an order in which to look at the tables.  Based on the ON clauses, only 2 orderings are possible.  The following discussion develops a set of `INDEXes` that should speed up the query at least some.

---

Let's say it picks logs as the first table.  And rewrites the joins into this order:

```
    FROM  logs
    JOIN  users     ON logs.user_id = users.user_id
    JOIN  computers ON users.computer_id = computers.computer_id
```

So, `logs` needs at least the first column of this to handle the `WHERE` (and maybe the `ORDER BY`).

```
INDEX(capture_timestamp,  -- for the `WHERE`
      user_id, event_target, event_title, activity_id)  -- Optional, for covering
```

Then JOIN to `users` via what I assume to be the `PRIMARY KEY(user_id)`?

Then JOIN to `computers` via what I assume to be the `PRIMARY KEY(computer_id)`

---

If, instead, it picks `computers` to be first:

```
    FROM  computers
    JOIN  users  ON users.computer_id = computers.computer_id
    JOIN  logs   ON logs.user_id = users.user_id
```

`computers` needs

```
INDEX(status, account_id,  -- first, in either order,
      computer_id, os, computer_name)   -- for covering
```

To JOIN to `users`, it needs

```
INDEX(computer_id,   -- first
      user_id, username)   -- optional, for covering
```

To JOIN to `logs`:

```
INDEX(user_id,    -- first
      capture_timestamp,   -- (a range) second
      event_target, event_title, activity_id)  -- optional, for covering
```

Bottom line:  Provide all the indexes given above; let the optimizer choose the table order.

If `event_title` is `TEXT`, you can't include it in an `INDEX`.  In that case, shorten those 2 indexes to these two:

```
 INDEX(capture_timestamp)
 INDEX(user_id, capture_timestamp)
```

If I am wrong about the `PRIMARY KEYs`, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: I already have all the indexes you mention above.  I also tried moving the filtering all into WHERE while leaving ON just for relations.  The query takes the exact same time and the analyze shows the same as well.

Comment: @user756659 - Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the 3 tables.  There are some subtle things I need to look for.  (Moving between `ON` and `WHERE` has no effect on optimization, only on readability.)

Comment: Added to the original post.  There has to be a way around this.  As far as I know this is pretty standard as far as how the db is setup... like a hierarchy where the tables link to each other on a common column value.  In this case, accounts -> computers -> users -> logs.  Without being able to specify that `account_id` in the where I can't specify which 'account' the query is for.

Comment: any suggestions?  Given what you've said above it seems like I have to remove the normalization for all of these tables to use the indexes as intended if the WHERE and ORDER BY can only come from the same table.

Comment: Flip the columns in this:  KEY `account_id` (`account_id`,`status`), -- I don't like the index that the optimizer picked.

Comment: That doesn't change anything.